# Javascript program to check if a prompt character is in an array and alert answer

Tags: javascript, arrays, alert, prompt

I'm just trying to make a very simple program that takes in a character from a prompt, checks if it's in an array and then alerts an answer.  I'm in early learning and just found the new .include method but was also trying with just simple if/else statements. This almost seemed to work but just returns the same answer no matter the input.

```
var letters = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

var selection = prompt ("enter a letter")


if (letters.includes("selection") == "true") {
    alert ('yes');
    } 
    else {
    alert ('no');
    };
```

Then earlier I tried this but also couldn't get it to work:

```
var vowel = prompt ("enter letter");

var letters = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

if (letters.indexOf('letters') !== -1) {
 alert("Yes!");
 }
 else {
 alert("No");
  }
```

I'm sure the answer is a very newbie "duh" but help is appreciated and I'm trying to use simple structures just to learn basics rather than ideal, creative things I haven't gotten to yet....thank you.

Comment: In your first example, don't wrap selection in quotes. Every time you are checking if "selection" is in the array rather than the value that selection holds

Comment: Firstly remove qoutes from selection inside if

Answer (score 0):

You are trying ot check if the vowel exists but you are checking a full string instead of the variable created by your prompt. Don't do that. Check the variable you are creating.

Next, you can just do letters.includes, you don't need to check if the value is true or not because if includes is true it will execute as such.

```js
var letters = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

var selection = prompt ("enter a letter")


if (letters.includes(selection)) {
    alert ('yes');
} else {
    alert ('no');
};
```

Also, the reason you are failing on if == "true" is because that a true boolean ends up as an int while "true" will return NaN. You can't convert that string to a bool.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you pass variable name as a string instead of variable ref to the indexOf function argument ?

replace your code with this:

```
letters.indexOf(vowel) !== -1
```

in place of:

```
letters.indexOf('letters') !== -1
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers!  I knew it would be a "duh" answer as it always seems to be in coding.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to pass variable `selection` instead of string `'selection'` into `inludes()` and get rid of `== "true"`

```
    var letters = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
    var selection = prompt("enter a letter")

    if (letters.includes(selection)) {
        alert('yes');
    } else {
        alert('no');
    };
```

Almost had this one. Instead of passing `'selection'` into `indexOf()`, you needed to pass `vowel`.

```
    var vowel = prompt("enter letter");
    var letters = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

    if (letters.indexOf(vowel) !== -1) {
        alert("Yes!");
    } else {
        alert("No");
    }
```